# Error 404 with Angular 4 using routing on Tomcat 9 with Valve

Tags: java, apache, angular, tomcat, mod-rewrite

I'll tell you what happens by following steps:

1) I have my app project based on Angular 4.0.2. I'm using routing. These are my routes in app.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes =
[
{ path: '', component: LoginComponent },
{ path: 'dashboard',  component: DashboardComponent }, 
{ path: 'login',  component: LoginComponent }
];
```

So the first screen of the web application is Login.

2) I executed the command ng build -prod

3) I move the folder dist into Tomcat webapps folder

4) I modified the file index.html changing base href. Now it's

5) In /Tomcat9/conf/context.xml, I added the following instruction:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
```

6) I created the folder WEB-INF, then I created the file rewrite.config, this file contains:
     # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

7) I started Tomcat server

8) Next I openned a Mozilla browser and I put in address bar 
    localhost:8080/dist/
It appears the login screen with 2 textboxes (user and pass) and one button for login.

9)When I press the button with user and pass valid. it goes to dashboard screen and I see the address bar changes to:
localhost:8080/dist/dashboard.

10) After that, I go to address bar and I wrote manually: localhost:8080/dist/dashboard.

Then I press Enter and it appears Error 404.

It should keep showing dashboard screen and not Error 404.

This app works well in Apache server with .htaccess, but not in Tomcat 9

Why is not showing dashboard screen in this case if I configured the rewrite.config? what is missing in order to avoid error 404?

Comment: Any solution was found?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the rewrite rules are not working.
Try these rules:

```
#Check if the uri ends with an file extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\.(.*)$ [OR]

#Check if the uri contains /api/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)(/api/).*$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L]

#If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the above solutions, with angular 11 and tomcat 9, just now (2021), I've tried them, but with no results.
Then I came to a different approach, all in the war with angular app.

In web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/r404</location>
</error-page>
```

in the java source:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/r404/*"})
public class R404Servlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Override
  protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)    throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath());
  }
}
```