# Refresh The browser Angular app is not working. giving 404 error when I deployed the app in to apache tomcat

Tags: angular, tomcat, angular6, production-environment

I'm trying to figure out the way how to setup Apache Tomcat server to serve angular application on page refresh.

Routing will work only when i click but if enter path manually or if i do page refresh then its give me the 404 error.

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

1) Build angular application with:

```
ng build --prod --base-href ./
```

2) Also i added Rewrite rule in apache tomcat

In $ApacheLocation/conf/context.xml

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
```

In $ApacheLocation/conf/server.xml

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
```

But its not working for me.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: This is just enabling the RewriteValve. In addition to this you have to write the redirect rule as well as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55612266/1298824)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the solution to my question and i solved the problem.

Here's the step that, how i resolved the problem.

1) Created "WEB-INF/web.xml" in my angular src folder, the path is as follows

```
Your_Folder/src/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

2) In `web.xml` i added below lines,

```
<web-app> 
    <error-page> 
        <error-code>404</error-code> 
        <location>/index.html</location> 
    </error-page> 
</web-app>
```

3) Add external folder into `angular.json` so can while building application it will be available into dist folder,

In angular.json

```
"assets": [ "src/assets","src/favicon.ico","src/WEB-INF" ]
```

4) Build the application with below command,

```
ng build --prod --base-href=/myApp/
```

5) Rename the `dist` folder with `base-href` name

6) Copy the `dist` or `base-href` folder and paste into

```
apache-tomcat-8.5.37/webapps
```

7) Start the tomcat and your application will run, even after refresh the browser.

Comment: Step 1,2,3 did it for me. We use a variety of prop files and different deployment strat, so the remaining steps were slightly differen.

Comment: @JacobBarnes Yes you are right, rest of the steps depends.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert for Apache but here's what I found. 
Add a rewrite rule to the .htaccess file as shown

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

You can read more in 
https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/03/09/angularjs-html5-mode-or-pretty-urls-on-apache-using-htaccess/
or 
https://angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback-configuration-examples

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i already tried this and still no success.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem. Let me tell how I solved the problem.

create WEB-INF folder in your project folder. and create rewrite.config file.

**/WEB-INF/rewrite.config**

```
RewriteCond %{SERVLET_PATH} !-f
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.html [L]
```

Comment: Just i tried your solution but still facing same issue...can you give me little brief idea what you did.

Comment: My path of the WEB-INF folder is "apache-tomcat-8.5.37/webapps/WEB-INF/rewrite.config".

Comment: let try by building application with no base href `ng build --prod`

Comment: without base-href pages will not be serve.

Answer (score 0):

You have just configure the RewriteValve in server.xml. In addition to this you need to write the rewrite rule in rewrite.config.

**rewrite.config** -

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_PATH} !-f
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /index.html
```

The above rule is telling tomcat to redirect any request (deep linked request) to the index.html of the application. From here angular will take over and route to the correct component to be displayed.

I would suggest to host the application in a separate context path on tomcat rather than at the root. the configurations needed for this is explained in details on this blog - [Fixing deep linking issue – Deploying angular application on Tomcat server](http://codedumpster.nithinbiliya.com/deep-linking-issue-angular-application-tomcat-server/)

Comment: what is the issue? you should be able to create the file if you are a root user

Comment: I guess my problem was that the RewriteValve added in server.xml did not apply to my app. I had to add context.xml in META-INF with the valve defined there. Then it worked. Also I used a bit different rewrite logic as described https://stackoverflow.com/a/47919953/1278890

Answer (score -1):

You can use HashLocationStrategy as below in app.module.ts

```
providers: [
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
  ],
```

By using the hash location strategy, your application context and routes will be separated by a Hash(#) as in `http://localhost:4200/myapp/#/route`.

This way the 404 error will be resolved. we also have PathLocationStrategy but I was not able to get it to work.